# .net core health checks

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/22/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/)  for how to implement health checks in ASP.net core.

My question is how does on do it for non ASP.net core.

I would think lots of people running apps in docker containers and using the likes of the following in Dockerfile:

> HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:5000/healthz || exit

But not all apps are web apps, so for no web how do you monitor the health of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For none core apps you can just add a new controller and a get method

```
[RoutePrefix("healthz")]
public class HealthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet,Route]
    public IHttpActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This will do the same thing, if you want to check the health of any resources such as databases then you can put code inside the `Index` method to do these checks first and return a different status code if something is down such as

```
return InternalServerError();
```

Comment: How does that work as it will not be hosted as web server e.g. kestrel so controller can not be called?

Comment: Think I misunderstand your question then, is your question asking about non .net core ASP.Net web apps or applications that aren't web apps at all?

Comment: .net core console apps, which in the past would be windows services

Comment: Little late response here! Monitoring console apps would be done with other mechanisms such as STDERR